# ScrollView unable to display image which passed from another VC

Tags: ios, swift

I need to display the image pass in from the another `ViewController`

first,I have tested using only `ImageView` to display the image and it works as below:

Thanks. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var TempImgView: UIImgeView!
    var passInImg: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

       TempImgView.image = passInImg!

   }
```

When I use `UIScrollView` ( for scrolling the large passInImg) , below code not working

Probelm:

> error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   optional value

But I have tested the pass in image  in the above code.

what need to be done with the `scrollView`?

1. Should be used in `viewDidLoad`?

   class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var myUIScrollView: UIScrollView!

   var myImgView: UIImageView!
   var passInImg: UIImage?


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()


       self.myUIScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0

       self.myUIScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

       self.myUIScrollView.delegate = self

       myImgView.image = passInImg!

       self.myUIScrollView.addSubview(myImgView)

   }


   func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

       return myImgView
   }
   ```

Comment: You should also set the contentSize of the scrollView to size of the image

Comment: Not working after following your method-- add the  myUIScrollView.contentSize = myImgView.bounds.size BEFORE delegate = self

Comment: Does your image view has proper frame?

Answer (score 0):

First check if myUIScrollView is connected to an outlet in storyboard and always check before using an optional variable:

```
if let img = passInImg {
    myImgView.image =  img
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please `initialize` the `myImgView` with frame before set the image.

It return `nil` because the `myImgView` not `initalize`

```
myImgView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 300));
```

It works for me. Hope it will helps you.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the way you are declaring the UIImageView.
In the first case:

```
@IBOutlet weak var TempImgView: UIImageView!
```

`TempImgView` is an `@IBOutlet` and hence initialised whenever the storyboard view/xib is loaded.

But then when you are using the scrollview, you have declared the `UIImageView` as a class variable and not `@IBOutlet`.

```
var myImgView: UIImageView!
```

It has to initialised before you try to access it.
Try:

```
myImgView = UIImageView()
myImgView.image = passInImg!
```